# What is the difference between a skyrmion and a magnetic vortex?

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, spin-models, vortex, skyrmion

Skyrmions and magnetic vortices are spin structures occurring in magnets.

What are the differences between them? More specifically, I would like to understand their origin and how to distinguish them.

Comment: It's a good question - would you also be interested in seeing an answer in the context of HEP gauge theory rather than cond-mat?

Comment: Yes, I would, as long as I'll be able to see the analogy

Comment: I would recommend reading: "Topological Solitons" by N.Manton and P. Sutcliffe. They classify a vortex as a soliton in a 2d linear field theory, whereas a baby skyrmion (magnetic skyrmion) and a skyrmion are solitons in nonlinear field theories. But this classification might be dependent on the author of what you are reading.